# How to increase the size of SymPy LaTeX output in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, ipython, sympy

I have an IPython notebook in Vscode where I use SymPy to print formulas in LaTeX mode.

How can I increase the "font size" of the printed formulas?

Changing the editor zoom only affects the code in the code cells and leaves the LaTeX output unchanged.
Changing the view zoom does affect the size of the LaTeX output, but also affects the entire window (as intended). However, I would prefer to leave the view zoom unchanged.

Is there a way to increase just the size of the LaTeX output?

Reference image below, I find the formula a bit hard to read, especially the subscript x and z.

[image]

Edit:
I found a kind of workaround. You can change the presentation style in vscode by clicking on the </> symbol left of the output box. If you select `image/png`, the output will be a rendered image. The size of the image is affected by the `scale` parameter of `init_printing()`.

Still, this is not the solution I had hoped for.

Comment: SymPy's `init_printing` function has a `fontsize` option.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your image of code into a code block? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thanks for the suggestion, but the the `fontsize` option does not change the size of the LaTeX output. I tried fontsize='30pt' (default is 10pt) and the LaTeX output is still the same size.

Comment: @starball I'm aware of the problems with code screenshots, but this question is not about code. It's about increasing the output size in my IDE. The image serves as a reference to show my problem, formatting it as text defeats its purpose.

Comment: I don't know anything about sympy, so seeing the code, I (perhaps erroneously) assumed it was part of a [mre], in which case it should go in a code block and not an image. But if it's not part of a [mre], then it may be fine as is.

Comment: I guess you need to follow any documentation for the `printf` function ( have no idea what that is but it's not part of sympy).